# Showing empty option in Select Control when there is no value

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
class Index extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
          records:[],  
        } 
    }
.....
render() {
const columns = [
      {
        title: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'ID',
        key: 'ID',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.ID - b.ID,
        render: (val)=><div title={val} className="text_overlap">{val}</div>
      },{
        title: 'Module',
        dataIndex: 'Description',
        key: 'Description',
        sorter: false,
        render: (val, record, index) => <div title={'Module: ' + val} className="text_overlap d-flex">
             
              {record.IsEdit ? <Select mode="multiple"
              style={{ width: '80%' }}
              value={this.state.descr}
              placeholder="Please select"
              onChange={(e) => {this.setState({set:true, descr:e});}}
              filterOption={(input, option) =>
                option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
              }>
              {this.state.Modules && this.state.Modules.map((d) => <Select.Option value={d.Description}>{d.Description}</Select.Option>)}
            </Select>  : <div style={{maxWidth:'90%',overflow:'hidden', textOverflow:'ellipsis'}}>{val && val.join(', ')}</div>}
            {!record.IsEdit && <div className="mx-2" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} title={"Edit"} onClick={() => { this.doEdit(record,index); this.setState({descr:record.Description}) }}><i className="fa fa-edit" style={{  fontSize:17, marginTop: 0 }}></i></div>}
            {record.IsEdit && <div className="mx-2 pt-1" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} title={"Save"} onClick={() => { this.updateRecord(record); this.setState({descr:''}) }}><i style={{fontSize:17}} className={this.state.updating ? "fa fa-spin fa-spinner" : "fa fa-save"}></i></div>}
            {record.IsEdit && <div className="mx-2 pt-1" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} title={"Cancel"} onClick={() => { this.doCancel(record); this.setState({descr:''}) }}><i style={{fontSize:17}} className="fa fa-times"></i></div>}
              </div>
      }
      
    ];
```

[image]

I have a editable column in my grid.But if there is no value from the backend in some cases it shows an empty options. If it has values, no issues there. How to remove that empty value? I am using antd.

Answer (score 0):

If this.state.descr doesn't have any value, make it null.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a conditional rendering in your render method for `this.state.length > 0`